# CakePHP trouble with posting from select to controller

Tags: cakephp

The value of my select tag doesn't seem tto post to my controller, no matter what I try

The select tag

```
<select name="whatever">

<?php

foreach($packs as $packName => $pack) {

   echo " '<option value=" . $packName . '">' . $packName . '</option>';
}
?>
 </select>
```

Where I try to use it in controller

```
function procedures() {

    $errors = array();

    $otsing= "";

    if (!isset($this->data)) {

        App::import('Helper', 'Formatter');
        $formatter = new FormatterHelper(); 
        $this->data['start'] = 
            $formatter->FormatDate($this->Dating->Now());
        $this->data['end'] = $formatter->FormatDate($this->Dating->Now());

        if(!empty($_POST['whatever']))
        {
            $otsing = $this->$_POST['whatever']; 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The select name should be wriiten like

```
data[Formname][selectname]
```

if you want to give it in HTML format or you should use cakephp way to define dropdwon:

```
<?php
echo $form->select(‘whatever’,$packs)
?>
```